# tsql union, order by, and view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to pull a set of data from tables in different databases (on the same server (2014) and identical table structure) and have it in a view. I've found several discussions about set ordering and unions, but I having some problems figuring out the result set itself. Here is the script:

```
CREATE VIEW OrderCheck (Source, [Order No], [Date], FirstName) as

SELECT Top 2 'Set1', Order_No, format(Order_Date,'g'), First_Name
FROM        db1.dbo.Orders 
Union all
SELECT Top 2 'Set2', Order_No, format(Order_Date,'g'), First_Name
FROM        db2.dbo.Orders
Union all
SELECT Top 2 'Set3', Order_No, format(Order_Date,'g'), First_Name 
FROM        db3.dbo.Orders

ORDER BY    Order_No desc
```

If I run the select/union query by itself, I get these results, which is what I want:

```
Set3    60098   9/14/2016 8:32 AM   Lydia
Set3    60097   9/13/2016 12:28 PM  Jeané
Set1    30098   9/19/2016 4:12 PM   Joshua
Set1    30097   9/19/2016 1:35 PM   Cynthia
Set2    11050   9/20/2016 9:24 AM   Lorrie
Set2    11049   9/19/2016 11:12 PM  Dawnisha
```

But when I use the view (select * from OrderCheck), I get this:

```
Set1    10011   11/14/2013 9:13 AM  Jaime
Set1    10012   11/14/2013 9:54 AM  Eric
Set2    10011   11/14/2013 9:13 AM  Jaime
Set2    10012   11/14/2013 9:54 AM  Eric
Set3    60098   9/14/2016 8:32 AM   Lydia
Set3    60097   9/13/2016 12:28 PM  Jeané
```

Finally, if I run the query inside or outside of a view but without any "order by", I get this:

```
Set1    10011   11/14/2013 9:13 AM  Jaime
Set1    10012   11/14/2013 9:54 AM  Eric
Set2    10011   11/14/2013 9:13 AM  Jaime
Set2    10012   11/14/2013 9:54 AM  Eric
Set3    10011   11/14/2013 9:13 AM  Jaime
Set3    10012   11/14/2013 9:54 AM  Eric
```

So you can see that in the view, set 1 rows replace set 2 rows except for the string literal. And without the "order by", set 1 replaces both set 2 *and* set 3. "Union All" vs "Union" makes no difference, nor does the number of TOP rows requested. Seems bizarre to me, but I'm hoping there is a logical explanation that I'm just missing despite my research.

Thank you so much!
Jim Kelleher

Comment: As I know, you can't do order by inside view, it worked with you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ORDER BY` fulfils two completely different roles - it can define the sort order of a result set, or it can complete the definition of other functionality, such as `TOP` or `FETCH`. Sometimes it may fulfil both of these roles at the same time.

This is an alternative formulation of your query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Top 2 'Set1', Order_No, format(Order_Date,'g'), First_Name
FROM        db1.dbo.Orders ORDER BY <Set 1 TOP Definition Criteria) t (Setname,Order_No,Order_Date,First_Name)
Union all
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Top 2 'Set2', Order_No, format(Order_Date,'g'), First_Name
FROM        db2.dbo.Orders ORDER BY <Set 2 TOP Definition Criteria) t (Setname,Order_No,Order_Date,First_Name)
Union all
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Top 2 'Set3', Order_No, format(Order_Date,'g'), First_Name 
FROM        db3.dbo.Orders ORDER BY <Set 3 TOP Definition Criteria) t (Setname,Order_No,Order_Date,First_Name)

ORDER BY    <Result set sorting criteria>
```

Here you can explicitly indicate by which criteria each `TOP 2` should be selected. If you're using this within a view, however, you would omit the final `ORDER BY    <Result set sorting criteria>` since views cannot dictate a result set sorting criteria. At best, you might force the server to accept the *existence* of such an `ORDER BY` clause, but it will offer no actual guarantees.

It's unclear from your question what the actual criteria ought to be for each `TOP` definition.

Comment: Ah, very interesting. I was assuming that Order By would be applied to each select. It does seem to work that way when run "outside" the view.

Comment: @user3091705 - "seem" is the operative word. As you've already discovered through your own experiments, it's not guaranteed. I've shown in my answer a structure you can adopt if you want to explicitly control your query and guarantee the outcomes.

Comment: Also, would we not expect to see each select returning records from its associated table, even if in non-guaranteed order? But it's returning records from set1 even though set2 is specified.

Comment: Each inner select can only return rows based on its `FROM` clause. I suspect you've convinced yourself that there's data in `Set 1` that doesn't exist in `Set 2` when in fact that data does so exist.

Comment: Yes, thank you Damien. It works well with that structure. Also, I didn't realize column names for a sub-query could be specified using that parenthetical syntax. Nice to know!

Answer (score 1):

Order by  is not guaranteed unless you use an outer order by

```
select * from view
order by order_no desc/asc
```

guarantees order

Below is a Quote from [Itzik Ben-Gan](http://tsql.solidq.com/)

> The ORDER BY clause in the view(when using Top*) is only guaranteed
> to serve the logical filtering purpose for the TOP option. If you query the view and don’t specify an
> ORDER BY clause in the outer query, presentation order is not guaranteed

The Top 100 Percent is also harmfull as per this article..[TOP 100 Percent ORDER BY Considered Harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/queryoptteam/2006/03/24/top-100-percent-order-by-considered-harmful/).

*Emphasis Mine

Comment: Yes, but it is not the order of the results that's puzzling me, it's the fact that the rows seem to have incorrect data, which is making this hard to pinpoint.